# pytest class scope parametrisation not working as expected

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, parametrize

The idea is to re-create the 'connector' fixture for each 'port' parametrisation of the class. However, currently it only creates the fixture once for the whole test class and not on each param iteration. How would I make the fixtures scope only for each parametrisation of the class.

conftest.py -

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def connector():
    # RUN ON CREATE ...
    # connect to TCP
    
    yield tcp_client

    # RUN ON DESTROY ...
    # disconnect and destroy
```

test_device.py -

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('ports', [0, 2], scope="class")
class TestDevice:

    device_info = load_device_info('device_model')['device']

    def test_power_on(self, switcher, ports):
            # switch power on for the port the device is on

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('inputs', device_info['inputs'])
    def test_init_inputs(self, inputs, connector, ports):
            # send some messages over TCP network and set the inputs for the device
            #     destroy and recreate the simple_tcp_client fixture after each iteration of the class parametrization when it reaches this function ...


    @pytest.mark.parametrize("samplerate", [samplerate for samplerate in SampleRate])
    def test_run_device_tests(self, samplerate, ports):
            # run tests on each device with different samplerates ...
```

I've also tried this in conftest but get the same issue:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[0, 2], scope='class')
def ports(request):
    return request.param
```

The structure I want:

```
TestClass [port: '1', 2]
├─ power_on [port: 1]
├─ init_inputs [input: 1, 2], [new connector]
│  ├─ set inputs[1]
│  ├─ set inputs[2]
├─ run_test [samplerate [44100, 96000 ...]
│  ├─ run with [44100]
│  ├─ run with [96000]

TestClass [port: 1, '2']
├─ power_on [port: 2]
├─ init_inputs [input: 1, 2], [new connector]
│  ├─ set inputs[1]
│  ├─ set inputs[2]
├─ run_test [samplerate [44100, 96000 ...]
│  ├─ run with [44100]
│  ├─ run with [96000]
```

How it currently runs:

```
TestClass [port: '1', 2]
├─ power_on [port: 1]
├─ init_inputs [input: 1, 2], [new connector]
│  ├─ set inputs[1]
│  ├─ set inputs[2]
├─ run_test [samplerate [44100, 96000 ...]
│  ├─ run with [44100]
│  ├─ run with [96000]

TestClass [port: 1, '2']
├─ power_on [port: 2]
├─ init_inputs [input: 1, 2], [same connector]
│  ├─ set inputs[1]
│  ├─ set inputs[2]
├─ run_test [samplerate [44100, 96000 ...]
│  ├─ run with [44100]
│  ├─ run with [96000]
```

I'm new to pytest so maybe I'm not using fixtures and parametrization correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not to use the `class` scope for your `connector` fixture?

```
@pytest.fixture
def connector():
    # RUN ON CREATE ...
    # connect to TCP
    
    yield tcp_client

    # RUN ON DESTROY ...
    # disconnect and destroy
```

Comment: Yes and instead it creates a new connector twice in init_inputs on each iteration

Comment: But why you move the connector fixture in a separate file ``conftest.py``? I would try to move the fixture inside the class/module I would like the fixture to be reused/reinstantiated. Maybe move it into ``TestDevice``?

Comment: I've tried this and still does the same. The only reason I included it in conftest.py is because it allows me to reuse it again on any files within that dir